json file validation with schema not working
I am trying to validate a json file with a schema but it always says it is valid even when I am removing some fields from the loaded file, see:
import jsonschema
from jsonschema import validate

my_schema = {
    'ID': {'type': 'string'},
    'Country': {'type': 'string'},
    'Name': {'type': 'string'},
    'A': {'type': 'string'},
    'B': {'type': 'string'},
    'C': {'type': 'string'},
    'D': {'type': 'string'}
}


def validate_json(json_data):
    try:
        validate(instance=json_data, schema=my_schema)
    except jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError as err:
        return 'Given JSON data is Invalid'
    return 'Given JSON data is Valid'


# Function to validate the json file
def validate_json_syntax(json_file):
    try:
        with open(json_file, 'r') as f:
            data = json.load(f)
        return validate_json(data)
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        print('Read file: Unsuccessful - %s!' % e)
        return None


# Validate json file syntax
print(validate_json_syntax(file_name))

The file has following data stored:
[[{"ID": "101", "Country": "UK", "Name": "none", "A": "2", "B": "6", "C": "0", "D": "0"}, 
  {"ID": "102", "Country": "UK", "Name": "bla", "A": "1", "B": "2", "C": "0", "D": "0"}], 
  [{"ID": "110", "Country": "GB", "Name": "nana", "A": "2", "B": "6", "C": "0", "D": "0"}, 
   {"ID": "111", "Country": "GB", "Name": "bla", "A": "1", "B": "3", "C": "0", "D": "0"}]
]

But even when I change the file like:
[[{"ID": "101", "Country": "UK", "B": "6", "C": "0", "D": "0"}, 
  {"ID": "102", "Country": "UK", "Name": "bla", "A": "1", "B": "2", "C": "0", "D": "0"}], 
  [{"ID": "110", "Country": "GB", "Name": "nana", "A": "2", "B": "6", "C": "0", "D": "0"}, 
   {"ID": "111", "Country": "GB", "Name": "bla", "A": "1", "B": "3", "C": "0", "D": "0"}]
]

The outcome is still valid from json validate function with the schema.
How do I need to change the schema?

https://www.learnjsonschema.com/2020-12/validation/required/

I have done some changes in my schema but it still doesn't work as expected.

try adding the required: keyword to your schema : '... D': {'type': 'string'} },     "required": ["ID", "Country", "Name", "A", "B", "C", "D" ] }

Try this schema.
my_schema = {
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                'ID': {'type': 'string'},
                'Country': {'type': 'string'},
                'Name': {'type': 'string'},
                'A': {'type': 'string'},
                'B': {'type': 'string'},
                'C': {'type': 'string'},
                'D': {'type': 'string'}
                },
            "required": [
                "ID",
                "Country",
                "Name",
                "A",
                "B",
                "C",
                "D"
                ]
            }
        }
    }


this fixes it, the original post had items: [] which is valid JSON Schema, but invalid for the validation you are trying to achieve.  items: [] represents a tuple where each index is explicitly defined.  items: {} is an array instance without defining each index explicitly. It only defines that each index should match the defined schema.
